# EXC_BAD_ACCES error when reload tableview content

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

Once an array is properly filled, when I call it again using tableview reload, first time (after clean) returns an empty value and following executions returns EXC_BAD_ACCES. Trying to provide all code needed... Thanks for help!

in .h file:

```
    @interface userViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

        NSArray *appData;

        IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
        IBOutlet UILabel *status;
        IBOutlet UITableView *mainTable;
        IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *refresh; 
    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *status;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *mainTable;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) UIBarButtonItem *refresh;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *appData;

- (IBAction) refresca: (id)sender;
```

in .m file, when requestFinished function is executed, appData is properly filled.

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    NSLog(@"%@", [request responseString]);
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    activityIndicator.hidden = YES;

    appData = [[request responseString] componentsSeparatedByString: @"#"]; 

    int x =0;

    while (x<[appData count] - 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"Data = %@",[appData objectAtIndex: x]);
        x = x+1;
    }

}
```

However, after its execution, when reload tableview, appData seems that is empty and previous conted erased!!

```
2011-10-13 18:10:43.682 Nimbo[444:207] Data = <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x5c93dd0; frame = (0 0; 320 43); layer = <CALayer: 0x5c953b0>

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        [tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 412)];

        static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = (UITableViewCell*) [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        }
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


        int x = 0;

        if ([appData count] != 0)
           {
           NSLog(@"Data = %@",[appData objectAtIndex: 0]);
            }

        return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your instance variable `appData` is not retained.

EDIT: as others have said, using the property is the best way to go. That will retain your new `appData` as well as release objects previously assigned there.

Try changing:

```
    appData = [[request responseString] componentsSeparatedByString: @"#"];
```

to:

```
    self.appData = [[request responseString] componentsSeparatedByString: @"#"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem mostly lies here

```
appData = [[request responseString] componentsSeparatedByString: @"#"];
```

You are assigning an autoreleased object to `appData` which isn't the right way as you don't take ownership. You are also not releasing ownership on the previously held data. You should use the setter method of the `appData`.

```
self.appData = [[request responseString] componentsSeparatedByString: @"#"];
```

should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use property (`self.appData`):

```
self.appData = [[request responseString] componentsSeparatedByString: @"#"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is the problem or not, most probably not... But why define a property when you're not using the self.appData? Are you @synthesize appData?

When you use properties, calling self.property actually calls the generated setter and getter, and those work as specified on the property. So if you specify a property with retain, but you assign a convenience returned array to the variable itself, after the event loop the convenience array will get autoreleased and because you didn't retain the array, it will be erased from memory, losing everything you had in there, and what is probably happening in your case.